# JS перехватить Post запрос

Tags: javascript, post

Ситуация такова: есть большой объем JS кода. Необходимо создать прокладку, которая будет отлавливать попытки отправления запросов и будет считывать параметры (поля у post, а так же неплохо было бы получить поставленные cookie). Каким образом можно реализовать это?

Comment: Мне предложили переопределить xrh, но я не уверен, отразится ли это на скрипте. Честно говоря я не очень хорошо лажу с JS, но возникла необходимость.

Comment: Ну, не все запросы осуществляются через XHR, и те, что идут в обход, вы не поймаете при всём желании, если у вас доступ только к контексту страницы.

Comment: Звучит как: "Хочу перехватывать чужие запросы и куки через расширение на js")))
Думаю, в данном контексте, вы ответ не получите.

Comment: В google extension и firefox все проще, там можно поюзать и document.cookie, и спарсить запросы. Моя задача - авторизация на сайте, где cookie устанавливаются js скриптом, причем неявно.

Comment: @D-side я работаю со скриптом не через браузер, а через интерпретатор windows

Comment: Ого экзотика какая. Допишите в вопрос, это существенная деталь.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о XHR запросах:

```
var tempGlobal;

function addXMLRequestCallback(callback) {
    var oldSend, i;
    if (XMLHttpRequest.callbacks) {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push(callback);
    } else {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
        oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
            for (i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i](this);
            }
            oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}

addXMLRequestCallback(function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
});
```